# Chords are skipping a line in lilypond

Tags: lilypond

I'm trying to produce a piece containing only chords and lyrics in lilypond, and I want to use one set of chords for different verses. Yet, I don't understand why the chords won't appear over the second line in the following example.

```
versechords = \chords { g2 d f g}                                                                                                                            

verseI  = \lyricmode {This2 "is the" first verse \break}
verseII = \lyricmode {This2 "is the" second verse \break}

\new Score \with {
  \remove "Bar_number_engraver"
}
<<
  \new Chords {
    \versechords
    \versechords
  }
  \new Lyrics \with {
    \override VerticalAxisGroup.staff-affinity = ##f
    \override LyricText.parent-alignment-X = #LEFT
    \override LyricText.self-alignment-X = #LEFT
  }
  {
    \verseI
    \verseII
  }
>>

\layout {
  indent = 0
  ragged-right = ##t
  \context {
    \Score
    \override SpacingSpanner packed-spacing = ##t
  }
}
```

[image]

I can get the right result if I create one sequence of chords containing twice the chords of the verses, but I really want to define the sequence only once and use it multiple times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your mistake is in the very first line:

```
versechords = \chords { g2 d f g}
```

Note that `\chords` is an abbreviation for `\context ChordNames \chordmode`, so your double use of `\versechords` leads to two separate `ChordNames` contexts.  You want to use just `\chordmode` here, and `\new ChordNames` (and not `\new Chords`, please don't ignore warnings LilyPond issues!) around the double use of `\versechords`.